# Unable to import CSS and JS from node modules in index.html

Tags: reactjs

My react app compiled by `webpack` is unable to find packages in the `node_modules` folder. The URLs are correctly set from my `src/index.html` as follows:

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>
<body>
<div id="app"></div>
<script src="../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="/bundle.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**webpack.config.js**

```
let webpack = require("webpack");
let path = require("path");

let DIST_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname,"dist");
let SRC_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname,"src");

let config = {
    entry: SRC_DIR + "/index.js",
    output: {
        path: DIST_DIR + "/",
        filename: "bundle.js",
        publicPath: "/"
    },
    module:{
        loaders:[
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: [ 'style-loader', 'css-loader' ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.js?/,
                include: SRC_DIR,
                loader: "babel-loader",
                query: {
                    presets:["react", "es2015", "stage-2"]
                }
            }
        ]
    }
};

module.exports = config;
```

But the console reports the following errors which seem to ignore any `../` set in the beginning of the URL.

**Console Errors:**

> GET http://localhost:8080/node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css 
>   
>   GET http://localhost:8080/node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js

I tried to set relative paths using `./` as follows but with the same result

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./../node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">
```

and

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">
```

**Folder Structure:**

```
app/
 -dist/
    -bundle.js
    -index.html
 -node_modules/
 -src/
    -index.html
    -index.js
```

How do I do this right? Should I move node_modules into `src/` folder?

Comment: what are you using to serve index.html, webpack?

Comment: yes, I'm using webpack 2.4.1

Comment: what is your webpack config? try just ./node_modules

Comment: No change. It outputs the exact same error.

Comment: try to remove the dot also

Comment: Already tried it. That did not work.

Comment: then add this to your webpack config
```javascript
devServer: {
  contentBase: path.join(__dirname, "."),
  compress: true,
  port: 8000
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Where exactly should I add it? I tried adding devServer key in the config object and I get  `Cannot GET /`. Console reports `Refused to connect to 'https://cr-input.mxpnl.net/data?_channel_id=&_partner_id=39‌​571&_sub_id=0000&_ap‌​p_version=1.0.23&_ap‌​p=cs-dca' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self'". Note that 'connect-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback. `

Comment: I am sorry, you have to specify where the server root should be, in contentBase instead of the dot put the directory which should be the root.

Comment: Well, that almost worked. I used the url `/root/node_modules/...file.css`. It seems like it found the file but it doesn't parse as CSS. Console reports the warning: `Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html`. Also tried adding `type="text/css"` but without success.

Answer (score 0):

So the issue you are facing is probably due to your folder structure. If you place your index.html at root level your problem will likely to get resolved. [Here](https://github.com/upasanaa/react-fontAwesome-Jquery) is a simple github repository doing the same as yours.

Comment: I copied `index.html` to root, set `package.json` as `"build": "webpack -d && xcopy \"index.html\" \"dist/\" /F /Y && webpack-dev-server --content-base src/ --inline --hot --history-api-fallback"`. It compiles successfully but in the browser I get `Cannot GET /`. Console reports" `Refused to connect to 'https://cr-input.mxpnl.net/data?_channel_id=&_partner_id=39571&_sub_id=0000&_app_version=1.0.23&_app=cs-dca' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self'". Note that 'connect-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.`

Comment: Have you tried my github repository for your example?

Comment: why do you need to set --content-base in this example, in this case you want to serve your index.html from dist/ folder I guess.